# IDE plugin to check method boundaries, does it exist?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, intellij-idea, boundary

Suppose you're concerned with clarity of your code and would like to make sure users of your api are crystal clear as to how objects are created. You make them do things like

`new MomentInTime(new DayOfMonth(15), new HourOfDay(10), new MinuteOfHour(49), new SecondOfMinute(0));`

Where each class `DayOfMonth`, `HourOfDay` is pretty much identical to one another, a value store of some kind.

Now, when the time comes for you to use the value, using Java's `Calendar`, should value be illegal, we will get some kind of RunTimeException. Great.

Now .. Is it possible for us to set up Min, Max boundaries in our IDE (`Eclipse` or `Intellij`) that would warn us that value we're about to send to a method will result in an error?

Is there a plug-in and an annotation that would work together that would allow for such a warning?

Something along the lines of `@Boundaries {low=1, high=31}` along with IDE actually recognizing it would be great.

Please let me know if something like this exists.

Comment: I'd suggest constraining the values instead of complaining because someone tries to set your Int32 parameter to 0 (it would confuse the heck out of developers). If Java offers something similar to .NET's `Enum` it sounds like a job for it.

Comment: I've seen an annotation called @IntRange(min=1, max= 100000) in code searches. However, I have no clue, if it does what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Contracts for Java](https://code.google.com/p/cofoja/). It does have a rudimentary integration into Eclipse.

```
interface Time {
  ...

  @Ensures({
    "result >= 0",
    "result <= 23"
  })
  int getHour();

  @Requires({
    "h >= 0",
    "h <= 23"
  })
  @Ensures("getHour() == h")
  void setHour(int h);

  ...
}
```